# Filling DataGridView based on a scanned barcode number from a barcode scanner

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, barcode-scanner

I have been reading loads of questions and answers and even the .NET reference site. The code seems to be good but it's not working as expected.

I have a `TextBox` where a barcode scanner is used to scan barcodes and put the number in it. Once the barcode is received it has to detect the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and do a function that searches the database and add the item in a `DataGridView`.

The code is working but it's only adding 1 item to the `DataGridView` even if I scan multiple items.

Code:

```
 Private Sub txtmodel_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtmodel.KeyPress

    Dim purchasesource As New BindingSource
    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Return) Then


        Dim query As String
        query = "select  prod_name as 'Product Name',prod_cost as 'Cost', prod_price as 'Price' from  product_tbl where prod_STATUS = 'Active' and prod_code = '" & txtmodel.Text & "'"

        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(sql_get_purchase_item)
        purchasesource.DataSource = sql_get_purchase_item
        DataGridView1.DataSource = purchasesource
        da.Update(sql_get_purchase_item)

        MsgBox(sql_get_purchase_item.Rows.Count)

        barcode = txtmodel.Text 'decaled in the class

        TextBox1.Text &= barcode

        txtmodel.Focus()

        txtmodel.SelectAll()

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: second time scanning check the txtmodel_KeyPress event is firing or not??

Comment: Just for checking purposes i added a textbox so that each time ENTER is found in the KEYPRESS function it adds the text to the other txtbox. And it works. I can see all the barcodes stacking up in the multiline textbox

Comment: can you post full code??

Comment: I think its not saving the 2nd Product in the datatable ? am getting count as 1 each time but the textbox works, like it shows me all the barcodes i scan

Comment: you want to add the rows to the datagridview by scanning simultaneously

Comment: Yes. I want it to work like this:
1- I scan 1 BARCODE -> it search the database -> add to datagrid
2- Repeat step 1

Comment: filling the result to da.Fill(sql_get_purchase_item). what i am asking is sql_get_purchase_item type is dataset or datatable

Comment: Its declared in a module:
Public sql_get_purchase_item As New DataTable

Comment: Its a datatable

Comment: i have posted answer try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search that the scanned text is available in the database and add that row to the `DataGridView`.

Try the below code:

```
Private Sub txtmodel_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtmodel.KeyPress

    Dim purchasesource As New BindingSource
    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Return) Then

        Dim query As String
        query = "select  prod_name as 'Product Name',prod_cost as 'Cost', prod_price as 'Price' from  product_tbl where prod_STATUS = 'Active' and prod_code = '" & txtmodel.Text & "'"

        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(sql_get_purchase_item)
        If sql_get_purchase_item.tables(0).rows.count > 0
            For Each row As DataRow In sql_get_purchase_item.Rows
                DataGridView1.rows.add(row.Item("Product Name"),row.Item("Cost"),row.Item("Price"))
            Next row

        End If
        purchasesource.DataSource = sql_get_purchase_item
        da.Update(sql_get_purchase_item)

        txtmodel.Focus()

        txtmodel.SelectAll()

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, the `txtModel` gets a single product code at a scan. Once you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> you scan `product_tbl` for a specific product code and show it in the `DataGridView`. If my logic is correct, it will always only show you the last product scanned. That's because your code says so.

You will have to *add each product* to the `DataGridView` instead of assigning the query result (which is always one product) to the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`.

@Praba has provided the apt code for it.

Edited to add and comments:

```
  Private Sub txtmodel_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtmodel.KeyPress

  Dim purchasesource As New BindingSource
  If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Return) Then

    Dim query As String
    ' Add break point on the below line.
    ' Check the value of txtModel here.
    query = "select  prod_name as 'Product Name',prod_cost as 'Cost', prod_price as 'Price' from  product_tbl where prod_STATUS = 'Active' and prod_code = '" & txtmodel.Text & "'"

    ' Add a break point on the below line.
    ' Check the value of query variable, copy it and execute it query analyser to check the result.
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(sql_get_purchase_item)

    ' Commented as not required.
    ' purchasesource.DataSource = sql_get_purchase_item
    ' DataGridView1.DataSource = purchasesource
    ' da.Update(sql_get_purchase_item)


    If sql_get_purchase_item.tables(0).rows.count > 0
      ' For each is not really required as you should always get only 1 product as a result.
      For Each row As DataRow In sql_get_purchase_item.Rows
        ' Add a break point on the below line.
        ' Check the values of each column returning.
        DataGridView1.rows.add(row.Item("Product Name"),row.Item("Cost"),row.Item("Price"))
      Next row
    End If

    ' Commented as not required.
    ' MsgBox(sql_get_purchase_item.Rows.Count)

    ' Comment if not required.
    barcode = txtmodel.Text 'decaled in the class

    ' Modified for better view
    TextBox1.Text &= barcode

    ' Commented as not required.
    'txtmodel.Focus()
    'txtmodel.SelectAll()

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok so when you scan Shoe,
1. txtModel has the correct code.
2. Adds the product to Gridview when ENTER is pressed
Then you scan a Book,
1. txtModel has the book code
2. Either adds Shoe again or does not add book at all.
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes It adds its again but sames product as 1st one. Instead of adding 1 line SAYING BOOK. it adds the same SHOE line. But when i alert the text, they are both different. 1st time its BARCODE1, send time its barcode2

Comment: Hi i tried it and this is what i get same error:
https://ibb.co/jp3nGF
please check this link

Comment: Did you add break points and debugged the code to see the output as mentioned in the comments? Please do that. It will actually help you understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Also I would suggest you to declare sql_get_purchase_item locally to the function and not globally to the form or project.

Comment: added break points on the 3rd one it says:
Item = In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user.

Comment: THE rows of the datatable stays 1? why/

Comment: When in debug mode, click on Watch tab and add the required variables to watch, in your case row.Item("Column_Name") and it's value will be displayed in the value column of the window

Comment: That's coz when you say da.Fill(myDataTable), myDataTable is filled with all the rows from the giving SQL query and in your case the query is retrieving only one product with a specific product code, which will always be 1.

Comment: Found the culpit i think:
"select  prod_name as 'Product Name',prod_cost as 'Cost', prod_price as 'Price' from  product_tbl where prod_STATUS = 'Active' and prod_code = '" & vbCrLf & "790069403644'"

ITS PASSING " & vbCrLf & " THIS AS AN EXTRA part of the sql statement. HOw to remove haha i think this is an easy one

Comment: Like I said, debugging help! This is coming from the bar code reader most probably, so remove it before setting it to the txtModel. Or, use "...prod_code = '" & txtModel.Replace(Chr(10),"").Replace(Chr(13), "")

Comment: THANKS MATE @ATHAR13

Comment: If that solves your crisis do mark the answer to close the question and help others to gain & benefit from the knowledge.